# Bind onChange event inside a directive of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is an example of how I expect it to look like:

```
link: function (scope, element, attribute) {                
    // and these value we get inside link function
    // Listen for change events to enable binding
    // element.on('change', function () {
        //functionality here...
    // });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function listener() {
  return {
   link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
     elem.bind("change", function() {
       alert('change');
     });
   }
  }
}

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('listener', listener);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <select listener><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
</div>
```

Comment: came for the same thing.. 'change' event does not get fired when value changes as a result of angular binding

Answer (score 0):

here are the example directive code for event binding in angular js

```
var myApp=angular.module('testApp',[]);
myApp.directive('clickme', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var clickedCallback = function() {
      alert('Hello World!')
    };
    element.bind('click', clickedCallback);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want doing almost the same you expect:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

function myDirective() {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
      element.bind('change', callback);

      function callback() {
        alert('change');

        // do some stuff here
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <input type="text" my-directive />
</div>
```

**Note**

More over, if it's supposed to do some manipulations with `scope` then `scope.$apply` should be used, because you're handling DOM events that are out of the Angular JS life cycle. In this case, `callback` should look like:

```
function callback() {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        // do some manipulations with `scope`here
    });
}
```